# Tutors students association same user table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a users tables in which I have a role_id columns that links to a roles table that contains the roles of user (student, tutor, admin, etc).

Tutors can have many students and a student can have many tutors. Is there a way that I can represent this relationship by using the same users table. This is a many to many relationship but using the same table. I would like to be able to display on a UI the students for a tutor and tutors that a student is assigned to. At this point I'm not concerned about the UI but about how to represent this in a database.

I don't want to create a different table for Tutors and Students because then I would have to manage different tables for different types of users.

Please let me know the best, most efficient way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: "because then I would have to manage different tables for different types of users" -- how so? It's typical to create a table where each entry represents a tutor-student relationship.

Comment: Just normalise, like normal

Comment: So you mean I would create a separate table with columns tutor_id and student_id (a many-to-many relationship kind of thing)? @UlrichEckhardt? Is that the best and most efficient way?

Comment: "best and most efficient" is very subjective and open to debate. It is a common approach and it works, how about that?

Comment: I had the same idea too. Thanks @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 0):

You should have below tables:

```
1. users : store all type of users
2. roles: all roles with id(student, tutor ...)
3. student_tutor (student_id, tutor_id)
```

It is a cleaner format to store many-to-many relationship